# How to bind data to label in angular2

Tags: angular

Is it possible to bind data to a label using `ngModel`? I want to display data fetched from the database and display using labels and not input(textbox).

Comment: As Roman said you can use `[]` to display the value in the label, If you are going to show it in label, the value are not going to change in HTML, so I think there is no need for two-way data binding (`ngModel`) in your case

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are 3 options :

1. `<label [value]="someValueExpression"/>`
2. `<label>{{ value}}</label>`
3. when you are using form:

   ```
   <label for="name">Name</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required>
   ```

Answer (score 5):

`ngModel` works only for form's controls, which get input from the user. You need to use `{{ }}` syntax.

```
<label>{{ yourData }}</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the way to achieve two way data binding for the **label** control.

```
  <label for="name">{{name}}</label>
```

in your ts

```
export class MyComponent {
           name="Wick";    
      //one of the hrml controls calls this method
           somebodyCalledMe(){
          this.name="John Wick";
}
```

So now whenever the name property changes automatically the label's text will also change accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The `ngModel` only works for form's input controls. The label is not a form control.

You can bind other properties with `[]` i.e. the property binding.

```
<label [value]="expression"/>
```